# CSV merge never ends

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, vba

I have a VBscript that combines multiple CSV files into one single CSV file. The script perfectly combines the files when run for the first time. But, when re-run to append data to the existing CSV, the Process never ends or an infinite loop starts.

Below is the function for merging data. 
"FilesToWorkWith" is a dictionary with file names as keys and file objects as values. I hope i have explained the problem.

```
Set FilesDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For each iFile in objFiles

    If(CheckExtension(iFile) = True) Then               
            FilesDict.Add iFile.Name, iFile         
    End if

Next

Function MergeCSV (UIDReportsFolderLocation,strCombinedUIDFileName)   

FilesToWorkWith = FilesDict.Keys
Set outFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(UIDReportsFolderLocation & "\" & strCombinedUIDFileName & ".csv", ForAppending, CreateIfNotExist, OpenAsASCII)

Dim firstFile
firstFile = True

For Each Key in FilesToWorkWith

    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FilesDict(Key), ForReading)   

    If Not firstFile = True Then
        objFile.Skipline
    End if

    Do 
        strTemp = objFile.ReadLine

        If Not strTemp = "" Then                
            outFile.WriteLine strTemp
        End if

    Loop Until objFile.AtEndOfStream = True

    objFile.Close

    firstFile = False


Next

outFile.close
Set iFile = Nothing
set objFile = Nothing
Set FilesDict = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

End Function
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious reason would be that your output file is being processed as an input file and just loops forever appending itself to itself. You're not showing how FilesToWorkWith is being initialized so it's impossible to tell for sure but that's the first place I would look.

Comment: I think you are Right!! Thanks for the Pointer. Let me check

Comment: That doesn't show enough to really clarify anything... the key question is, when you "re-run to append data to the existing CSV", is your destination file in objFiles? How do you get the list of files in objFiles? Are you getting a directory listing that will now contain your output .csv file since the script has been run once already and it was created on the first run?

Comment: ThankYou Levesque...your first suggestion was Right.  I fixed it by adding an If Loop to make sure that the output csv doesn't get added into the dictionary. It avoided Output being processed as an Input.  And, yes..i was getting a directory listing of all the files in objFiles for the  folder that contained the output csv as well.